# rosserial_arduino avoid lost messages

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i'm using rosserial_arduino package to communicate with my robot hardware.
I'm noticing that some messages are lost in both ways (Arduino->Desktop & Desktop->Arduino)
I'm not publishing at high speed, to be more precise messages are sent with several seconds interval between them.

Is there a way to make message delivery guaranteed?
I can wrap messages in services and use the service responses as aknowledges for but it sounds pretty ugly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198137/rosserial_arduino-avoid-lost-messages/) by [Wedontplay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18883/wedontplay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2014-11-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some "in depth" debugging I discovered that in my case the problem was caused by a buffer overflow on arduino serial rx buffer.
In this case higher baud rates increase the problem :)
Is easy to modify the buffer size on arduino source though.

---

Originally posted by [Wedontplay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18883/wedontplay/) with karma: 42 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0